# Change default form in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have custom forms for my list.

[image]

How to change default display/edit/new forms to those files with "-ifs.aspx" ?

Even better, can I do this without using SharePoint Designer? Is it possible to set default forms from web UI or maybe with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using powershell, should be something like:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://path/to/web
$list = $web.GetList("/server/relative/path/Lists/ListUrl")
$list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl = "/server/relative/path/Lists/ListUrl/displayifs.aspx"
$list.DefaultEditFormUrl = "/server/relative/path/Lists/ListUrl/editifs.aspx"
$list.DefaultNewFormUrl = "/server/relative/path/Lists/ListUrl/newifs.aspx"
```

You cannot change these properties from the UI.

Comment: mdmazzotti, you can change it from designer UI , as mentioned by prasad

Answer (score 10):

You can set it as default from SharePoint Designer 2013 as well. You need to select the form and then it will enable the "Set as default" button control in the Ribbon.

[image]

Comment: @Tschareck while the marked answer works, I think this should be the selected answer.